# CMD User Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, users

I'm working in a small business and I am the administrator of the Active Directory using Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 7 machines.
I want to create a user who can only access the CMD (find the MAC ADDRESS) and to be able change the IP(static) of the PC . All the other users are restricted and cannot access anything except the shares to access their files . I need this kind of user for my helper , in order to check their MAC addresses and then assign them Static IPs I will give him.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the user to the local [Network Configuration Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754921(v=ws.10).aspx) group, which will allow them to modify TCP/IP settings on the computer without being an administrator.

You can use something like Group Policy Preferences or Restricted Groups GPOs to push this out across all relevant computers.